# error in load () funtion when try to laod .RData format

Tags: r, load, rdata

I need to convert a  shapefile (.shp) formate into .RData format. I used the following codes but when I load the RData format file I get error

Code:

```
# to save .RData format which runs smoothly without error
save(trainData, file = "trainData1.RData")

# to laod the .RData file
load(trainData.RData)

Error Message:
Error in load(trainData.RData) : object 'trainData.RData' not found
```

Please point out where I'm making mistake!

Comment: you need to quote the string otherwise R looks for a variable named trainData.RData. so just try `load("trainData.RData")`

Comment: please, read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: also you saved the file as trainData1.RData but are trying to load trainData.RData (without the 1)

Answer (score 0):

I kept serching found out that that double inverted commas are needed when loading the .RData

Missing 1 from `load(trainData1)` was just a paste error that I did while posting.

well this worked,

```
save(trainData, file = "trainData1")
load("trainData1")
```